# how can I convert DTO to Entity when an attribute refers to the same class

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

when I want to convert DTO to Entity in the subcategory attribute, it does not allow me the data type and I get the following error:
incompatible types: Category cannot be converted to CategoryDTO.

How can I solve that ?
Thank you very much and a thousand apologies if there are errors

class CategoriaConverter

```
@Override
public CategoriaDTO fromEntity(Categoria entity) {
    if(entity == null) return null;
    Set<CategoriaDTO> categoria = desdeCategoria(entity.children);
    return CategoriaDTO.builder()
            .id(entity.id)
            .nombre(entity.nombre)
            .subcategoria(entity.subcategoria)
            .children(categoria)
            .build();
}

@Override
public Categoria fromDTO(CategoriaDTO dto) {
    if(dto == null) return null;
    Set<Categoria> categoria = desdeCategoriaDTO(dto.children);
    return Categoria.builder()
            .id(dto.id)
            .nombre(dto.nombre)
            .subcategoria(dto.subcategoria) // <- error incompatible types: Category cannot be 
            .children(categoria)            // converted to CategoryDTO.   
            .build();
}

public Set<CategoriaDTO> desdeCategoria(Set<Categoria> categoria){
    if (categoria == null) return null;
    return categoria.stream().map(c -> {
        return CategoriaDTO.builder()
                .id(c.id)
                .nombre(c.nombre)
                .build();
    })
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}

public Set<Categoria> desdeCategoriaDTO(Set<CategoriaDTO> categoriaDTO){
    if (categoriaDTO == null) return null;
    return categoriaDTO.stream().map(c -> {
        return Categoria.builder()
                .id(c.id)
                .nombre(c.nombre)
                .build();
    })
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

class Categoria

```
@Id
public String id;

@Column(name = "nombre", nullable = false, length = 200)
public String nombre;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_subcategoria")
public Categoria subcategoria;

@Builder.Default
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "subcategoria", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public Set<Categoria> children = new HashSet<>();
```

class CategoriaDTO

```
public String id;
public String nombre;
public CategoriaDTO subcategoria;
@Builder.Default
public Set<CategoriaDTO> children = new HashSet<>();
```

Comment: Your  `subcategoria` from  `Categoria` not same as  `subcategoria` from 'CategoriaDTO'. 
Try  making them same.

Comment: thank you very much, solved the problem. eternal thanks

Comment: How did you solve that? Did my approach work or you did your own? If my approach works, I can add it as answer, otherwise you can add yours.

Comment: could you add it as an answer?

Comment: change the subcategoria attribute: CategoriaDTO by Categoria in the class CategoriaDTO and it works

Comment: Please check, I have added the ans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `subcategoria` from `Categoria` not same as `subcategoria` from `CategoriaDTO`. Try making them same.
All the best!

Comment: Please mark it as Accepted Answer if you feel useful